# Split words in many columns sql

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, split, multiple-columns

I have a table column with these values:

```
Column-desc
------------------
"car broken"
"motorcycle broken"
"motorcycle clean"
"motorcycle clean and broken"
------------------
```

and I need to make a select that returns this:

```
return-desc1 | return-desc2 | return-desc3 |return-desc4 
------------------------------------------------------
car          |  broken      |              |
motorcycle   |  broken      |              |
motorcycle   |  clean       |              |
motorcycle   |  clean       | and          | broken
-------------------------------------------------------
```

(yes, max ll return 4 desc).
Could I use a regex for this case?

If this helps: I am using Oracle 10g

Comment: this might get you going in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123585/how-to-split-a-single-column-values-to-multiple-column-values

Comment: cool, it ll help-me, i can make step by step.

Comment: it dont work in oracle =[

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
    regexp_substr("Column-desc", '\S+', 1, 1) as "return-desc1",
    regexp_substr("Column-desc", '\S+', 1, 2) as "return-desc2",
    regexp_substr("Column-desc", '\S+', 1, 3) as "return-desc3",
    regexp_substr("Column-desc", '\S+', 1, 4) as "return-desc4"
from your_table
```

Comment: perfect this is a perfect answers!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly my suggestion would be to get the column-desc and do the split work on the programming layer. It would be easier and probably more optimal that way.