# SQL: How to count occurrences based on file extension

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which returns a column of values:

```
?????? ?? ?????? ??????? ?.?..xlsx
1028-13055 Single Patient Focus Wave 3.sav
2.xlsx
2011 BBQ (13Dec2013).sav
2014 Health IT Purchasing Intentions Survey Results.xlsx
2014 Safety Training and Safety Professionals Survey.sav
```

How do I count the number of occurrences based on the file extensions? In the above example, we have three rows for the xlsx extension and two for the sav extension?

Comment: This would help you only the delimeter is not space but dot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123585/how-to-split-a-single-column-values-to-multiple-column-values

Comment: What RDBMS you use (MySQL,Oracle,...)?

Comment: @ABCD Usually STRING functions depends on it.

Comment: Why do you say that it is only 2 .sav?  i count 3. is there some criterion i am missing?

Comment: Sorry, just manual miscount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT extension, 
       Count(*) AS ExtensionCount 
FROM   (SELECT RIGHT(name, Charindex('.', Reverse(name)) - 1) AS Extension 
        FROM   files) t 
GROUP  BY extension
```

SQL fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/27269/5

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT RIGHT(yourcolumnname,CHARINDEX('.', Reverse(yourcolumnname)) -1)
FROM yourtable
```

to isolate just the extension part and then count the occurrences

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
SELECT colcnt, 
       Count(*) TotCnt 
FROM  (SELECT RIGHT(col, Charindex('.', Reverse(col)) - 1) ColCnt 
       FROM   yourtable)x 
GROUP  BY colcnt
```