# SQL Column has a value I need to split into two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, split

For example

I have:

```
PN*BR        PN
872*07       872
8445*07      8455
```

I need a new BR column:

```
PN*BR        PN     BR
872*07       872    07
8445*07      8455   07
```

Comment: I can't see how this can be a copy of that specific question. They have very little in common. It may be a copy of other questions, but not that linked question

Comment: I agree with @t-clausen.dk this question is different because of the PN column -- it is not simply a string split.  Gordon's answer shows that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
select t.*,
       replace(replace([PN*BR], PN, ''), '*', '') as BR
from table t
```

Repeated values are a problem.  And now that the question is tagged with a database, I would suggest:

```
select t.*,
       replace([PN*BR], PN + '*', '') as BR
from table t
```

Comment: What about the PN column?

Comment: +1 I agree with the reasoning

Comment: hopefully [PN*BR] will not contain values like '07*07'

Comment: Hmmm seems the question changed

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Actually it can.  When you create a question or comment you have a few minutes "grace" period to make changes -- these changes don't show up on the history and (more importantly for my saving face) they don't generate an "update" message to the page so if you catch the original version you don't see the update without a hard refresh.  SO has one of the best UIs around, but this is one feature that can cause some slight confusion.  Sure is nice when you see that typo right after a submit.

Comment: @Hogan . . . That is a good point, and I use it quite frequently.  I am deleting all my comments about this.  Including this one (I hope) in a few minutes.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT LEFT([PN*BR],PATINDEX('%*%',[PN*BR])-1) AS PN,
       RIGHT([PN*BR],LEN([PN*BR]) - PATINDEX('%*%',[PN*BR])) AS BR
FROM   Table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.*,
       STUFF([PN*BR], 1, CHARINDEX('*', [PN*BR]), '') BR
FROM <yourtable> t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(PN*BR,1,CHARINDEX('*',PN*BR,1)-1) as PN, SUBSTRING(PN*BR,CHARINDEX('*',PN*BR,1)+1,LEN(PN*BR)-CHARINDEX('*',PN*BR,1)) as BR 
FROM Table
```

Answer (score -1):

Answered here: [How to split a single column values to multiple column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123585/how-to-split-a-single-column-values-to-multiple-column-values)

Extract:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN name LIKE '% %' THEN LEFT(name, Charindex(' ', name) - 1)
         ELSE name
       END,
       CASE
         WHEN name LIKE '% %' THEN RIGHT(name, Charindex(' ', Reverse(name)) - 1)
       END
FROM   YourTable
```

Comment: there is no name column in the question and the question does not want to split on space.

Comment: just trying to illustrate that the question has answer at the referred question and extracted the query from there.