# separate the check-in and check-out form a column datetime data type msssql

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime, time-and-attendance

I need to separate the checkintime column as AM as checkin and PM as checkout;

[image]

Comment: add your mssql query here..

Comment: kindly view the image here http://postimg.org/image/zc3r0ba71/ @Rahul Dambare

Comment: kindy view the image form the link     http://postimg.org/image/zc3r0ba71/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query .. in like clause add your search criteria.

```html
SELECT CASE
         WHEN checktime LIKE '%AM%' THEN LEFT(checktime, Charindex(' ', checktime) - 1)
         ELSE name
       END,
       CASE
         WHEN checktime LIKE '%PM%' THEN RIGHT(checktime, Charindex(' ', Reverse(checktime)) - 1)
       END
FROM   YourTable
```

For more check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123585/how-to-split-a-single-column-values-to-multiple-column-values)

Or try this solution -

```html
select ParsedData.* 
from MyTable mt
cross apply ( select str = mt.String + ',,' ) f1
cross apply ( select p1 = charindex( ',', str ) ) ap1
cross apply ( select p2 = charindex( ',', str, p1 + 1 ) ) ap2
cross apply ( select Nmame = substring( str, 1, p1-1 )                   
                 , Surname = substring( str, p1+1, p2-p1-1 )
          ) ParsedData
```

For more info click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

Comment: NOT YET WORKING , kindly see this picture to  http://s7.postimg.org/p4dl4swpn/Untitled.jpg                                                     my code is : SELECT CHECKINOUT.USERID, Ent_Staff.StaffName,CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME FROM Ent_Staff 
INNER JOIN USERINFO ON USERINFO.BADGENUMBER=Ent_Staff.Bio_Id 
INNER JOIN Mas_Shift ON Mas_Shift.Shift_Id=Ent_Staff.Shift_Id 
INNER JOIN checkinout ON checkinout.USERID=USERINFO.USERID 
WHERE checkinout.CHECKTIME >= '01/27/2016' AND checkinout.CHECKTIME < '01/28/2016 ' AND CHECKINOUT.USERID IN (9,15) 
ORDER BY checkinout.CHECKTIME @Rahul Dambare

Answer (score 0):

I have developed an Attendance system few days ago. Most of the time attendance machines just save a log for your entry. If an employee punches 5 times there will be 5 entry in that day for that employee. What I did I separated all the entries for a single day of an employee and took the first and last entry for check-in and check-out. Querying with AM/PM is not a good idea, both check-in or check-out can be AM or PM.