# We need to split data for two columns in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We need to split data for two columns in sql server.

```
CREATE TABLE #t (Id int,Number varchar(32),Name varchar(32));    

Insert Into #t(Id, Number,Name)
Values(123, '1,2,3','a~b~c') ,
(456, '1,2,3,4','a~b~c~d'),
(789, '1,2','a~b')

SELECT *FROM #t
```

Input:

```
Id  Number  Name
123 1,2,3   a~b~c
456 1,2,3,4 a~b~c~d
789 1,2 a~b
```

We need output in below format:

```
Id  Number  Name
123 1   a
123 2   b
123 3   c
456 1   a
456 2   b
456 3   c
456 4   d
789 1   a
789 2   b
```

Comment: Why down vote? :-|

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: have a look on this similar answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123585/how-to-split-a-single-column-values-to-multiple-column-values

Comment: I Tried using xml and and Cursor but it is working for only one column. I am not able to split same time data from 2 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a parser and a Cross Apply

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  #t A
 Cross Apply (  Select Number=C.RetVal
                      ,Name  =D.RetVal
                  From (Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.Number,',')) C
                  Join (Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.Name,'~')) D
                    on (C.RetSeq=D.RetSeq)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Number  Name
123 1       a
123 2       b
123 3       c
456 1       a
456 2       b
456 3       c
456 4       d
789 1       a
789 2       b
```

The UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
```

> **Edit  If you Can't use the UDF - We can move the UDF code into the two sub-queries to produce the same results**

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  #t A
 Cross Apply (  Select Number=C.RetVal
                      ,Name  =D.RetVal
                  From (
                        Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                              ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                            From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(A.Number,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                            Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                        ) C
                  Join (
                        Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                              ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                            From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(A.Name,'~','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                            Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                        ) D
                    on (C.RetSeq=D.RetSeq)
             ) B
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the method using cte..

```
;WITH cte_1
AS
    (SELECT Id,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID,LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))))RNO
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS Number

    FROM
    (
    SELECT Id
           ,CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(Number,',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
    FROM   #t 
    )t
    CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n))
,cte_2
AS
    (SELECT Id,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID,LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))))RNO
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS Name

    FROM
    (
    SELECT Id,CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(Name,'~','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
    FROM   #t 
    )t
    CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n))
SELECT a.id,a.Number,b.name
FROM cte_1 a JOIN cte_2 b
    ON a.id=b.id and a.RNo=b.RNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way with XML and CTEs:

```
DECLARE @x xml

SELECT @x = (
    SELECT  Id as '@id',
            CAST('<n number="'+REPLACE(Number,',','"/><n number="')+'"/>' as xml),
            CAST('<w name="'+REPLACE([Name],'~','"/><w name="')+'" />' as xml)
    FROM #t 
    FOR XML PATH('i')
)

;WITH numbers AS (
SELECT  t.v.value('../@id','int') as id,
        t.v.value('@number','nvarchar(10)') as number,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.v.value('../@id','int') ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as RN
FROM @x.nodes('/i/n') as t(v)
), names AS (
SELECT  t.v.value('../@id','int') as id,
        t.v.value('@name','nvarchar(10)') as [name],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.v.value('../@id','int') ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as RN
FROM @x.nodes('/i/w') as t(v)
)

SELECT  n.id,
        n.number,
        nn.[name]
FROM numbers n
INNER JOIN names nn
    ON n.id = nn.id and n.rn = nn.rn
```

Output:

```
id  number  name
123 1       a
123 2       b
123 3       c
456 1       a
456 2       b
456 3       c
456 4       d
789 1       a
789 2       b
```

I use `SELECT NULL` in ROW_NUMBER() part to get ordering as is. But it can cause some problems like not right ordering.