# How to remove special characters from name excluding salutation (Mister, Ms., Mrs., Doctor )?

Tags: sql-server, special-characters

I want to remove special characters form name excluding salutation part and Need to separate the first , last name and salutation.

```
Create table Employee_Name(Emp_Name varchar(20))
insert into  Employee_Name values('Dr. Sana .Singh');
insert into  Employee_Name values('Mrs. Ashley;');
insert into  Employee_Name values('Mr. Simon-');
insert into  Employee_Name values('Ms. Ale Martin galyx');
insert into  Employee_Name values('Doctor. Blank Smith&');

I need output to be

     Emp_Name            Salutation   First_Name    Last_Name
 Dr. Sana Singh              Dr.          Sana        Singh
 Mrs. Ashley                 Mrs.         Ashley    
 Mr. Simon                   Mr.          Simon 
 Ms. Ale Martin              Ms.          Ale         Martin
 Doctor. Blank Smith         Doctor.      Blank       Smith
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123585/how-to-split-a-single-column-values-to-multiple-column-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting names can be a slippery slope.  However, if you are looking for the first 3 strings, consider the following.  Easy to expand, I'm sure you can see the pattern 1,2,3,...  (I don't have much imagination)

```
Select A.Emp_Name
      ,Salutation = IsNull(B.Pos1,'')
      ,First_Name = IsNull(B.Pos2,'')
      ,Last_Name  = IsNull(B.Pos3,'')
 From  @Employee_Name A
 Cross Apply (
              Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
                    ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
                    ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
              From (Select Cast('<x>' + Replace([dbo].[udf-Str-Strip-Non-Alphanumeric](A.Emp_Name),' ','</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML) as xDim) A
             ) B
```

Returns

```
Emp_Name                Salutation  First_Name  Last_Name
Dr. Sana .Singh         Dr          Sana        Singh
Mrs. Ashley;            Mrs         Ashley  
Mr. Simon-              Mr          Simon   
Ms. Ale Martin galyx    Ms          Ale         Martin
Doctor. Blank Smith&    Doctor      Blank       Smith
```

**Now,** stripping the the non-ALPHA characters would require a UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Strip-Non-Alphanumeric](@S varchar(max))
Returns varchar(max)
Begin
    Declare @RetVal varchar(max) = ''
    ;with  cte1(N) As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(N) As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@S),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d)
    Select @RetVal = @RetVal + Substring(@S,N,1) 
     From  cte2
     Where Substring(@S,N,1) Like '[a-z,A-Z,0-9, ]'
    Return Replace(@RetVal,'  ',' ')
End
--Select [dbo].[udf-Str-Strip-Non-Alphanumeric]('some & text. /+= a  and zip 02806')  --Returns: some  text  a  and zip 02806
```

Comment: Thanks John , It helped me after.. few changes

Comment: @Sans Happy it helped.  Just curious, what changes did you make.  Perhaps it may help me as well.

Comment: Actually not the few changes ..but almost changed the query , bt got the idea from yours

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution, hope this helps you.

```
  SELECT 
  Emp_Name
 ,  Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(Emp_Name), '', ''), 1)) As [Salutation]
 , Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(Emp_Name), '', ''), 2)) As [First_Name]
 , Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(Emp_Name), '', ''), 3)) As [Last_Name]

  FROM  (Select Emp_Name from Employee_Name
  ) As [x]
```

Output:

[image]

Do edit if you need any improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows:

```
DECLARE @EMP TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),EMP_NAME VARCHAR(100),SALUTATION VARCHAR(100),FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(100),LAST_NAME VARCHAR(100),COMMON VARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(100),@ID INT
INSERT INTO @EMP (EMP_NAME,SALUTATION,COMMON) SELECT EMP_NAME,SUBSTRING(EMP_NAME,0,CHARINDEX(' ',EMP_NAME)+1),REPLACE(EMP_NAME,(SUBSTRING(EMP_NAME,0,CHARINDEX(' ',EMP_NAME)+1)),'') FROM EMPLOYEE_NAME

DECLARE C CURSOR FOR
SELECT COMMON,ID FROM @EMP
OPEN C
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @NAME,@ID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
IF(CHARINDEX(' ',@NAME))>0
BEGIN
UPDATE @EMP SET FIRST_NAME=(SELECT SUBSTRING(@NAME,0,CHARINDEX(' ',@NAME)+1)) WHERE ID=@ID
UPDATE @EMP SET LAST_NAME=(REPLACE(@NAME,(SUBSTRING(@NAME,0,CHARINDEX(' ',@NAME)+1)),'')) WHERE ID=@ID
IF(CHARINDEX(' ',(SELECT LAST_NAME FROM @EMP WHERE ID=@ID)))>0
BEGIN
    UPDATE @EMP SET LAST_NAME=(SELECT SUBSTRING(LAST_NAME,0,CHARINDEX(' ',LAST_NAME)+1) FROM @EMP WHERE ID=@ID) WHERE ID=@ID    
    END
END
ELSE
BEGIN
UPDATE @EMP SET FIRST_NAME=@NAME WHERE ID=@ID
END
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @NAME,@ID
END
CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C
SELECT EMP_NAME,SALUTATION,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME FROM @EMP
```