# SQL Server split string with delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an input string

```
100|2|3,101|2|1,103|2|3.
```

I would like to parse and add this in table having 3 columns so it should go f.x

```
 col1 col2 col3 
 100   2     3
```

similar other data separated by comma as record and `|` as column.

Thanks

nik

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a single column values to multiple column values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123585/how-to-split-a-single-column-values-to-multiple-column-values)

Answer (score 1):

Or this way:

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(value, Charindex('|', value) - 1),
    SUBSTRING(value, Charindex('|', value) + 1,Len(value) - Charindex('|', Reverse(value)) - Charindex('|', value)),
    RIGHT(value, Charindex('|', Reverse(value)) - 1)
FROM
    string_split('100|2|3,101|2|1,103|2|3',',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
DECLARE  @TAB TABLE(COLUMN1 INT, COLUMN2 INT, COLUMN3 INT)

DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(MAX)='100|2|3,101|2|1,103|2|3,'
SELECT @STRING = 'SELECT ' + REPLACE( REPLACE (@STRING, ',','
UNION ALL 
SELECT '),'|',',')

SELECT @STRING = SUBSTRING(@STRING,1,LEN(@STRING)-18)


INSERT INTO @TAB
EXEC(@STRING)

SELECT * FROM @TAB
```

And the result will be

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | COLUMN3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
|     100 |       2 |       3 |
|     101 |       2 |       1 |
|     103 |       2 |       3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Declare @temp table(col1 int,col2 int ,col3 int)
   Declare @pos int,@str nvarchar(max),@len int

   Set @str='100|2|3'
   Set @pos=1

Select @len=len(@str)

Insert into @temp
Select substring(@str,@pos,charindex('|',@str,@pos)-1),
       substring(@str,charindex('|',@str,@pos)+1,charindex('|',@str,@pos)-3), 
       substring(@str,charindex('|',@str,charindex('|',@str,@pos)+1)+1,@len)
Select * from @temp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ;WITH tb(s)AS(
        SELECT '100|2|3' UNION
        SELECT '101|2|1' UNION 
        SELECT '103|2|3'
  )
 SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(s,'|','.'),3)
       ,PARSENAME(REPLACE(s,'|','.'),2) 
       ,PARSENAME(REPLACE(s,'|','.'),1)  
 FROM tb
```

```
(No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)
100 2   3
101 2   1
103 2   3
```