# Break line on varchar string when delimeter SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have SQL `SELECT` query with long string, example:

```
SELECT RTRIM(CAST(DNH_INFO AS VARCHAR(150)))
```

**`'_This is _a very _long string _separated _with underline'`**

as i result a want to break lines by underline but still remain the same string, exmaple:

```
'_This is

 _a very

 _long string

 _...'
```

Is there any SQL function with which i can solve this problem?

Thanks for help!

Comment: I think you should mark SQL db engine (MSSQL, MySQL, Oracle, Postresql, DB2, Access, etc.)

Comment: ...then you can give a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123585/how-to-split-a-single-column-values-to-multiple-column-values     or similar

Comment: You want it as a separate row or into different column?

Comment: Yes but this is not what i want.
I want is as a one rown just with line breaks. NOT different column.

Comment: What is your RDBMS?

Comment: The solution would be different for different RDBMS, so it is important to mention just one.

Comment: It's Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@makaroN you can replace the space and underline with a LineFeed and Carriage Return and then re-add the underline. Alternatively you can use just the carriage Return (char(13) or reverse char(13) + char(10) if you do not need the extra line space. See the example below.

```
SELECT REPLACE('_This is _a very _long string _separated _with underline', 
               ' _', char(10) + char(13) + '_')
```

p.s if executing in management studio you may want to select Results to Text to immediately see the format.

Comment: Thanks @trincot was just editing to show the underscore.

Comment: Windows newline is CrLf, not LfCr, so I'd say you need `char(13) + char(10)` to get a line break.

Comment: Yep it is which I mentioned, but his example shows a large space between the lines which you'd get by reversing to LfCr... at least on management studio.