# How to standardize a column to be able to parse into multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

There are a lot of [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123585/how-to-split-a-single-column-values-to-multiple-column-values) on how to split a single column value into multiple columns, however I am having trouble standardizing data in the column to be able to use those techniques. What is the best approach for standardizing the below example?

For example:

```
**emails**
first_email,second_email
third_email; fourth_email
fifth_email ;sixth_email
seventh_email, eight_email
ninth_email.tenth_email
```

My expected output from standardization is:

```
**emails**
first_email, second_email
third_email, fourth_email
fifth_email, sixth_email
seventh_email, eight_email
ninth_email, tenth_email
```

Comment: If possible, I would highly suggest changing your database design to store only a single email in each row.  Another issue is that periods are allowed characters in email addresses.  So splitting on them wouldn't necessarily produce your expected results.

Comment: Sadly, this is data from a database that I do not have control over and so have to restructure to fit into a better database design.

Comment: A comma or semicolon are valid separators for multiple email, but a period is not (since it is commonly used as `first.last@domain.com`).  Is `.` really a separator between two email addresses?, or is `.` part of a valid email address?

Comment: I would suggest using regular expressions to parse the list. I doubt it's possible without regexp.

Comment: Thanks, and yeah there are some emails with . as a separator.

Comment: In your sample above, are there only two emails per row in the single column?  Or are all 10 in the same tuple (“cell”)?

Comment: Are there other email where the `.` is part of the email address, or are all `.` used to separate two email addresses?

Comment: There are up to 5 emails per row in the column, they are not in one cell. There are other emails where the `.` is part of the email address.

Comment: How many records are we talking about?  Can you manually sort through a few stragglers if necessary?  The `,` and `;` are no problem, the `.` on the other hand will cause you a lot of grief.

Comment: If the `.` wasn't used to sometimes be part of an email and other times separate two email, it would be easy.  I'll post an example.

Comment: That might have to be the approach there are around 26 thousand records. I am probably going to have to manually sort through the stragglers.

Comment: If at least there was space after the separating `.`! But it should be easy to find those with `email LIKE '%@%@%'`. This finds records with 2 or more `@` once you have separated the begnin cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows how you can normalize the formatting, but because the `.` character is sometimes used in an email address and other times used to separate email addresses, you should probably **not** include the replace for the `.`, and just work through those manually.

You can used a nested `replace()` to eliminate the spaces first, then replace the valid email address separators with `,[space]`.

```
declare @str varchar(max) = 'first_email,second_email
third_email; fourth_email
fifth_email ;sixth_email
seventh_email, eight_email
ninth_email.tenth_email'

select replace(replace(replace(replace(
         @str, ' ',   ''), -- a space is not valid in an email
               ',', ', '),
               ';', ', '),
               '.', ', '
       )
```

Which returns:

```
first_email, second_email
third_email, fourth_email
fifth_email, sixth_email
seventh_email, eight_email
ninth_email, tenth_email
```

Comment: Replacing `'.', ', '` will not work with `fn.ln@provider.com`.

Comment: Yes, that is why I said she should **not** include the replace for `.`.  She should really clean those records up first and exclude the `'.', ', '` from the the final script.