# Split SQL Server Column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table which name is AbundanceImpact.

```
Monetary~50
Monetary~120
Monetary~200
Monetary~269.90
Monetary~125
Magnanimous~50
Monetary~22.05
Unlimited~500
Monetary~150
Monetary~300
Monetary~21.89
Monetary~10.95
```

So I want the all integer values only with SUM.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a single column values to multiple column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123585/how-to-split-a-single-column-values-to-multiple-column-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below logic-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=44262a576efb3015cbf7930b21e63d19)

```
SELECT 
SUM(
    CAST(
        RIGHT(
            Column_name,
            LEN(Column_name) - CHARINDEX('~',Column_name,0)
        ) 
        AS FLOAT
    )
)
FROM AbundanceImpact
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `charindex()` :

```
select t.col, substring(t.col, charindex('~', t.col) + 1, len(t.col)) as val
from table t;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, yeah it work but i want also sum values of all records.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8685822e9d5f58725616ea5faaa8ee2e)

```
SELECT SUM(
           CAST(
                RIGHT(Value, 
                            LEN(Value) - (CHARINDEX('~', Value))) 
                AS  Decimal(18, 2)
               )
      ) Total
FROM 
(
    VALUES
    ('Monetary~50'),
    ('Monetary~120'),
    ('Monetary~200'),
    ('Monetary~269.90'),
    ('Monetary~125'),
    ('Magnanimous~50'),
    ('Monetary~22.05'),
    ('Unlimited~500'),
    ('Monetary~150'),
    ('Monetary~300'),
    ('Monetary~21.89'),
    ('Monetary~10.95')
)v(Value)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: @Waqas Ali Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use this logic

```
right('Monetary~120', len('Monetary~120')-CHARINDEX('~','Monetary~120'))
```

for your column with sum function.

Comment: Request you to provide the complete solution with a brief description. Also how if is better than others already available answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `stuff()` for this:

```
select sum(try_convert(numeric(20, 4),
                       stuff(col, 1, charindex('~', col), '')
                      )
          )
```

If you actually want to ignore the fractional components, then you would use `numeric(20, 0)` -- or something similar.  The `20` seems big enough for your data.